# Applying Location Moves Object Origin to World Origin

Tags: transforms

I'm having an issue with blender 2.76 where every time that I apply location, it moves the origin of the object to the world origin. I looked around for some answers and the only one I found suggested that I accidentally applied a key-frame, however I checked and no key-frames were to be found. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: What are you expecting to see when you apply the location?

Comment: Maybe you made a confusion with the 'Clear Location' ?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is exactly what "apply location" is supposed to do.  Maybe you need a new question that explains the behavior you want and asks what workflow will accomplish it.

Answer (score -2):

There is an option in 2.83 solving your issue, but no idea if it's in 2.76. The option is in the same menu that contains *Apply* Location. I throw empathy your way as it doesn't make sense that 'applying' a new location 'resets' it to the world origin.

The option you are looking for is *Location to Deltas*. This actually applies the location back to null values to wherever it resides, so no "offset" transfers over to whatever you want to do with it.